# Confused with DFS implementation

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

[image: Graph image]

```
public void dfs(){
    ArrayList<Node> exploredList = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack s=new Stack();
    s.push(this.rootNode);
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        Node n = (Node)s.pop();
        exploredList.add(n);
        printNode(n);
        ArrayList<Node> childList = getChildNodes(n);
        for (Node child : childList){
            if (!exploredList.contains(child) && !s.contains(child)) {
                s.push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A D C F B E
```

I am confused with DFS algorithm. The above code adds all child nodes to the stack, removes it from the stack and visits until it reaches the end node, while the other implementation (following reference link) adds one node to the stack, visits until it reaches the end node and backtracks.

Is the above code implementation of the DFS algorithm? If yes? How it is different from other DFS implementations? The output of other DFS algorithm should be:

Output:

```
A B E F C D
```

Reference:
[Introduction to Graph with Breadth First Search(BFS) and Depth First Search(DFS) Traversal Implemented in JAVA](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32212/Introduction-to-Graph-with-Breadth-First-Search-BF)

Comment: Yes the code posted implements  DFS and the two outputs are valid DFS results. DFS implementation can vary. For example, the order by which you iterate over the children's return by `getChildNodes(n)` may change the search order.  Add `Collections.shuffle(childList)` before the for-loop  and you may get different valid DFS paths on every run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes it a DFS (*depth*-first search) is the fact that it is traversing the graph by continuously visiting deeper and deeper nodes in the graph before backtracking and visiting other nodes which have been added to the stack. **Note:** this does not guarantee visiting the nodes in a specified order. Two perfectly good implementations of DFS can have entirely different outputs if they simply choose to visit the nodes in a different order, such as starting from the left `(A -> B)` rather than the right `(A -> D)` side.

Answer (score 0):

The output is different but your implementation was correct. I do not know how you constructed your own graph but I think its different because the algorithm visited the neighbors of root node from right to left.

Your neighbors of root node (A) is an ordered array which are [D, C, B]

So A visited D first, then is C and so on... its just from right to left. After all, it really depends on the way you constructed your graph.

I'm assuming that your graph is reversed.